# Is "Whom" correct here?

Tags: grammar

Is the use of "whom" wrong here:

*"This question is better answered by the UN Security Council whom are the United Kingdom, the United States, France, Russia and China."*

Since I can replace "Whom" with the subjective pronoun "they"... does that mean "Who" should be used instead?

Comment: _Who_ should definitely be used here (or, better still, _which_ as Lambie suggests). _Whom_ is only appropriate in the object case.

Comment: You have a good idea with who=they, and whom=them.

Comment: I don't believe English ever uses *whom* with the verb *to be*, except when there are prepositions involved (e.g., *many of whom are*). Some other languages, like French, do (or rather they can use *que* with *être*), and my guess is that this was translated a little bit too literally from one of these languages.

Comment: The problem with this question is that the usage of "better answered by the UN Council + relative pronoun who or whom is just plain wrong. Councils are not countries so it is a mistake to say who or whom. So, it is a disservice to the OP to answer the question as posed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, "whom" is the accusative (or "objective") form of "who."

And yes, in the clause "The council, who are ___," *council* should be in the nominative or subjective case. Don't get confused by what's going on in the larger sentence; within the scope of this clause, it acts like a subject: "The council are."*

And yes, when unsure, you can try substituting other pronouns that have separate forms for nominative and accusative: he/him, she/her, they/them, we/us, I/me.

* Note, there are other problems in this clause. The biggest is that "are," the verb "to be," equates things, and a council is not "the same thing as" a country or countries. To use a simpler example, you might say "the bowling team includes Sam and Sue," or any number of other constructions involving words like "compose," "comprises," "made up of," etc. But it would be too much of a shortcut in logic to say "the bowling team *is* Sam and Sue." The clause could also benefit by being set off with a comma.

Comment: REPHRASED: The problem should be answered by your parents who/whom are your mother and father. I'm going to say that "who" is the better of the two. EDITED Oh, you're saying "yes" whom *is* wrong.

Comment: I say that to characterize a council as are countries is a writing mistake, a knowledge mistake.

Comment: @Lambie Good point, though presumably the author "extends" the country to refer to its delegates, as in "Canada beats US in hockey." No argument that the sentence could be clearer with a comma, for one thing, and maybe without wading into the "can we use a collective singular noun with a plural verb" issue. I was trying to stick only to the core question and restrain myself from offering a full rewrite. But Des, if the sentence is yours, feel free to seek more coaching, especially at a place that can offer more individualized and wholistic advice than Stack Exchange is meant to.

Comment: Canada beats US in hockey is an entirely different thing. Here, there is no valid argument and it is a disservice to the OP to answer it as written.